# Can I format a disk from GRUB?

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, opensuse

Opensuse 11.4 seems to be creating problems with booting from USB devices. (I have read in a couple places that people are having similar problems.)

Every time I try to boot from a different live USB image, I see a GRUB screen flash and the hard disk starts to boot up.
The only live image I have had success with booting was another OpenSuse 11.4, then I got the options to install or run live.
I was thinking of just wiping the hard disk and seeing if that made a difference.
Can I get into the grub limited command line, can i format from here?
Is some other way of installing over the WAN from inside the Suse OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grub is a bootloader, not a formatter. If you can run `gparted` from the Grub command line, then you're in luck.

**EDIT:**

[Some Googling](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=format%20from%20grub%20terminal) leads me to believe that you *might* be able to do it, but I'm not sure. See this [list from the GRUB manual of the available commands in GRUB](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_12.html). It seems that you can make new partitions but I don't know if you can format existing ones.

Comment: cant run gparted, i dont think i have root filesystem loadedm i get options such as blocklist, boot, cat, chainloader, cmp, color... there is a terminal option, but if i type it, it just says: console and nothing happens

Comment: @bboyreason - See my edit. There's a list of GRUB commands available in the GRUB manual.