# Bootable windows pen drive is not detected by acer PC with ubuntu installed

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb-flash-drive

I used my macbook with bootcamp to create a bootable windows pen drive.
Now I'm trying to install windows on my computer with an Acer mainboard. I went to BIOS and set `Removable Device` as `1st Boot Deice`. Anyway the computer just continues to boot ubuntu from my `2nd Boot Device`. Also when I hit F12 key during startup to enter boot menu, my pen drive is not listed as a boot device. Why is this happening and how can I boot from my pendrive?

EDIT: I just tried with an old original windows XP DVD and it is also being ignored and not listed as a bootable device. I really don't have any idea what to do now.

EDIT2: Some BIOS settings, that I thought, might possibly be relevant:
`Advanced`->`Legacy USB support`: `Enabled`
`Authentication`->`Secure Boot`: `Disabled`
`Security`->`Removable Device Boot`: `Enabled`
`Boot Options`->`1st Boot Device`: `Removable Device`
`Boot Options`->`Boot Menu`: `enabled`
`Boot Options`->`fast boot`: `disabled`

Comment: 1. Unrelated to the already installed OS (Ubuntu). 2. The problem is likely the way you're doing the USB installer and/or firmware (UEFI) settings. Some Acer need a few changes in order for external media to be "trusted".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Well, about first: I thought that, too, but questions like this https://shttps://superuser.com/questions/269240/can-i-format-a-disk-from-grubuperuser.com/questions/269240/can-i-format-a-disk-from-grub made me think, it might be relevant. About secondd: So what does that mean? What can I do about it? How can I cahnge UEFI settings?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm currently trying to create the USB installer in a different way, using unetbootin instead of MacOS native bootcamp. lets see if that's gonna change anything. But as you can see in my EDIT: An original Windows XP DVD is also not being detected. I'm really getting desperate. I actually installed ubuntu from USB drive just a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Neither Unetbootin nor any other tool you can use in Mac will work with the new Microsoft ISOs. Only the official media creation tool (requires Windows), Rufus (same) or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185 (Ubuntu). Windows XP is NOT compatible with UEFI so it wouldn't boot anyway.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia So I can't use ANY tool on Mac to create a bootable windows Pen drive?

Comment: AFAIK no, you can't (with the current crop of Microsoft ISOs). For aditional details I refer you to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for your help. I'll try and find some Windows laptop then. I'll leave the question open though, maybe someone knows something we don't...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I just got it working with microsoft media creation tool. You might make that an answer. I still had to choose the boot decice manually using the boot menu though. Boot priority didn‘t work.

Comment: Well, thanks for the offer to write an answer but I think that there are already many similar questions with similar answers.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I have had issues in the past booting from a USB 3 port. Could you try it on a USB 2 port and see if that helps?